# cast child to parent and back to child in C# like you can in a View

Tags: c#, casting, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a method like this:

```
public ParentItem GetParentItem()
{
    return GetChildItem();
}

public ChildItem GetChildItem()
{
    return new ChildItem();
}

public void Run()
{
    var item = GetParentItem();
    var castedItem = (ChildItem) item;
}
```

Now the cast fails and I understand its because you can't cast a Car into Ferrari. However, I am certain that there is a way to achieve the above because I have done so with views in an mvc 5 application.

I have created a partial view which takes a model of `ChildItem` and when I call the view I pass the `ParentItem` and the view is able to extract the values that only `ChildItem` knows about.

I have 2 questions:
1. Why does the above work for Views?
2. How can I get it work in an actual c# class?

My only plausible theory is that when the object is passed to view it is serialized and the types don't make much of a difference because the structures are identical.

Comment: Without seeing the relationship between `ParentItem` and `ChildItem` it is hard to say why this fails. In any case, what does Car and Ferrari have to do with Parent and Child?

Comment: what is your definition for ParentItem and ChildItem ?

Comment: As stated by @NetMage this should cause no problems. As you can see from [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TRDYAE).